# is it possible to write a junit kind of unit testing framework without using any reflection facilities?

Tags: java, reflection, junit

I would like to know what would be the impact if a unit testing framework (for Java specifically) does not use any of the Reflection facilities. For example, if junit doesn't use Reflection at all to invoke tests, what will be the impact on its usage or features that it currently supports.  Are there any alternatives to match the flexibility of Reflection APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflection is used for configuration purpose. So the runner will know what methods to run for test and what methods to use for the setup and teardown of the tests. You could put that kind of configuration in an external file like xml and read it from there.

After knowing the names of the methods for running, reflection is used to actually allocate the methods and run them. I don't see a way you can do it in another way unless you actually write a some kind of a function in which you specifically call each test method. And then call this function in a main test suite function. Or you could make a preprocessor that write that kind of function for you from the information you specify in the configuration. But why would you want to ? It will only save you the time of the test runtime checks vs the one time compilation. It has very little advantage.